# R- create dataset by removing duplicates based on a condition - filter

Tags: r

I have a data frame where for each day, I have several prices. 
I would like to modify my data frame with the following code :

```
newdf <- Data %>%    
 filter(
if (Data$Date == Data$Echeance) {
  Data$Close == lag(Data$Close,1)
} else {
  Data$Close == Data$Close
}
)
```

However, it is not giving me what I want, that is : 
create a new data frame where the variable `Close` takes its normal value, unless the day of `Date` is equal to the day of `Echeance`. In this case, take the following `Close` value. 
I added filter because I wanted to remove the duplicate dates, and keep only one date per day where `Close` satisfies the condition above.

There is no error message, it just doesn't give me the right database.

Here is a glimpse of my data:

```
 Date                Echeance            Compens.  Open  Haut   Bas Close 

1 1998-03-27 00:00:00 1998-09-10 00:00:00     125.   828   828   820  820.   197     
2 1998-03-27 00:00:00 1998-11-10 00:00:00     128.   847   847   842  842.   124     
3 1998-03-27 00:00:00 1999-01-11 00:00:00     131.   858   858   858  858.     2     
4 1998-03-30 00:00:00 1998-09-10 00:00:00     125.   821   821   820  820.    38     
5 1998-03-30 00:00:00 1998-11-10 00:00:00     129.   843   843   843  843.     1     
6 1998-03-30 00:00:00 1999-01-11 00:00:00     131.   860   860   860  860.     5
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: No need to use `Data$something` when you've already pipped `Data` like this `Data %>% ...`. Then `if else` will modify / update your column based on a condition, so you should expect the same number of rows, where `filter` will exclude some cases based on a condition, so you would expect fewer rows. How can you combine `filter` and `if else`? Try to update the column first and then apply your filter.

Comment: Also, note that `lag` will get you the previous value and not the next (following) as you mentioned. Would be good to show an example of data and your expected output. Please make sure you include cases where `Date` is equal to `Echeance` and some duplicate cases so we can understand how you logic works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for `ifelse`, with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
    mutate(Close = ifelse(Date==Echeance, lead(Close,1), Close))
```

Here an example:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(var_new = ifelse(date1==date2, lead(var,1), var))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# date1      date2        var var_new
# <date>     <date>     <int>   <int>
# 1 2018-03-27 2018-03-27    10      11
# 2 2018-03-28 2018-01-01    11      11
# 3 2018-03-29 2018-02-01    12      12
```

The function `lead` will move the vector by 1 position. Also note that I created a `var_new` just to show the difference, but you can mutate directly `var`.

Data used:

```
dat <- tibble(date1 = seq(from=as.Date("2018-03-27"), to=as.Date("2018-03-29"), by="day"),
              date2 = c(as.Date("2018-03-27"), as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-01")),
              var = 10:12)
dat
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# date1      date2        var
# <date>     <date>     <int>
# 1 2018-03-27 2018-03-27    10
# 2 2018-03-28 2018-01-01    11
# 3 2018-03-29 2018-02-01    12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: you can use `distinct(data, Date)` to retain only unique dates

Comment: I used `newdf= newdf[!duplicated(newdf$Date),]` and it works too, thanks.